# 3.5.2 Tao analysis, need help with proof verification.

Tags: real-analysis

> (Exercise 3.5.2 in Analysis by Tao) Suppose we define an ordered $n$-tuple to be a surjective function $x: \{ i \in \mathbb{N}: 1 \le i \le n\} \to X$ whose range is some arbitrary set $X$ (so different ordered $n$- tuples are allowed to have different ranges); we then write $x_i$ for $x(i)$, and also write $x$ as $(x_i)_{1\le i\ \le n}$. Using this definition, verify that we have $(x_i)_{1\le i\ \le n} = (y_i)_{1\le i\ \le n}$ if and only if $x_i = y_i$ for all $1 \le i \le n$.

There is an exact copy of this question but it only provided a hint, wanted to check if my proof is correct:

$\Longrightarrow$ Assume $(x_i)_{1 \le i \le n}=(y_i)_{1 \le i \le n}$. We can rewrite the LHS as the function $x$, and the RHS as the function $y$, then by the axiom of equality of functions, we have that $x_i=x(i)=y(i)=y_i$ for  $1 \le i \le n$ as desired.

$\Longleftarrow$ Assume $x_i=y_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$, then $x(i)=y(i)$ for $1 \le i \le n$. Then, since the domain of both $x$ and $y$ is $\{i: 1 \le i \le n\}$. We have that both of their range is $\{x(i): 1 \le i \le n\}$ and since both are surjective, they also share the same codomain. Thus, by axion of equality of functions, we have $x=y$ and equivalently $(x_i)_{1 \le i \le n}=(y_i)_{1 \le i \le n}$ as desired.

Im particular not very confident for <==, feels abit iffy. How am i even allowed to say that $x_i=y_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$ tells us that $x$ and $y$ are surjective functions with domain in $\{i: 1 \le i \le n\}$. or am i allowed to do this by context of the question.

Comment: You took two $n$-tuples $(x_{i})_{1\leq i \leq n}$ and  $(y_{i})_{1\leq i \leq n}$. You know they are surjective and with domain $\{i \in \mathbb{N} : 1\leq i \leq n\} $ because by your definition, $n$-tuples are surjective and with that domain.

Comment: ah so like the assumption more explicitly would be: we have $x=(x_i)_{1 \le i \le n}$ and $y=(y_i)_{1 \le i \le n}$ st $x_i=y_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$, show that $x=y$

Comment: Of course, you are trying to prove something for generic $n$-tuples, not any two generic objects.

Comment: ah okay, got it, kind of confused why i was confused looking back